# RSPEC error: Validation failed: Email has already been taken Rails Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I encounter these errors when running the test:

```
  1) UsersController PUT 'update' authentication of edit/update pages for non-signed-in        users should deny access to 'edit'
     Failure/Error: @user = Factory(:user)
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Email has already been taken
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:130

  2) UsersController PUT 'update' authentication of edit/update pages for non-signed-in users should deny access to 'update'
     Failure/Error: @user = Factory(:user)
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Email has already been taken
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:130

  3) UsersController PUT 'update' authentication of edit/update pages for signed-in users should require matching users for 'edit'
     Failure/Error: @user = Factory(:user)
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Email has already been taken
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:130

  4) UsersController PUT 'update' authentication of edit/update pages for signed-in users should require matching users for 'update'
     Failure/Error: @user = Factory(:user)
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Email has already been taken
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:130

  5) UsersController PUT 'update' GET 'edit' should be successful
     Failure/Error: @user = Factory(:user)
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
      Validation failed: Email has already been taken
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:168

  6) UsersController PUT 'update' GET 'edit' should have a link to change the Gravatar
     Failure/Error: @user = Factory(:user)
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Email has already been taken
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:168
```

It doesn't seem to like the line:

```
before(:each) do
      @user = Factory(:user)
      test_sign_in(@user)
end
```

**Factory Code**

```
# By using the symbol ':user', we get Factory Girl to simulate the User model.
Factory.define :user do |user|
  user.name                  "Insert Name"
  user.email                 "email@example.com"
  user.password              "password"
  user.password_confirmation "password"
end
```

I assume that's what you want.

**User Controller Spec**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe UsersController do
  render_views

  describe "GET 'show'" do

before(:each) do
  @user = Factory(:user)
end

it "should be successful" do
  get :show, :id => @user
  response.should be_success
end

it "should find the right user" do
  get :show, :id => @user
  assigns(:user).should == @user
end

it "should include the user's name" do
     get :show, :id => @user
     response.should have_selector("h1", :content => @user.name)
end

it "should have a profile image" do
    get :show, :id => @user
    response.should have_selector("h1>img", :class => "gravatar")
end
  end

  describe "GET 'new'" do

it "should be successful" do
  get :new
  response.should be_success
end
  end

  describe "POST 'create'" do

describe "failure" do

  before(:each) do
    @attr = { :name => "", :email => "", :password => "", :password_confirmation => "" }
  end

  it "should not create a user" do
    lambda do
      post :create, :user => @attr
    end.should_not change(User, :count)
  end 

  it "should render the 'new' page" do
    post :create, :user => @attr
    response.should render_template('new')
  end
    end

describe "success" do

  before(:each) do
    @attr = { :name => "New User", :email => "user@example.com", :password => "password", :password_confirmation => "password" }
  end 

  it "should create a user" do
    lambda do
      post :create, :user => @attr
    end.should change(User, :count).by(1)
  end 
  it "should have a welcome message" do
          post :create, :user => @attr
          flash[:success].should =~ /Welcome to InTouch/i
  end

  it "should sign the user in" do
    post :create, :user => @attr
    controller.should be_signed_in
  end 
end
  end 

  describe "PUT 'update'" do

before(:each) do
  @user = Factory(:user)
  test_sign_in(@user)
end

describe "failure" do

  before(:each) do
    @attr = { :email => "", :name => "", :password => "", :password_cofirmation => "" }
  end 

  it "should render the 'edit' page" do
    put :update, :id => @user, :user => @attr
    response.should render_template('edit')
  end 

describe "success" do

  before(:each) do
    @attr = { :name => "New Name", :email => "user@example.org", :password => "newpassword", :password_confirmation => "newpassword" }
  end

  it "should change the user's attributes" do
    put :update, :id => @user, :user => @attr
    @user.reload
    @user.name.should == @attr[:name]
    @user.email.should == @attr[:email]
  end 

  it "should redirect to the user show page" do
    put :update, :id => @user, :user => @attr
    response.should redirect_to(user_path(@user))
  end 

  it "should have a flash message" do
    put :update, :id => @user, :user => @attr
    flash[:success].should =~ /updated/
  end 
    end 
  end 

  describe "authentication of edit/update pages" do

before(:each) do
  @user = Factory(:user)
end

describe "for non-signed-in users" do

  it "should deny access to 'edit'" do
    get :edit, :id => @user
    response.should redirect_to(signin_path)
  end

  it "should deny access to 'update'" do
    put :update, :id => @user, :user => {}
    response.should redirect_to(signin_path)
  end
    end

describe "for signed-in users" do

  before(:each) do
    wrong_user = Factory(:user, :email => "user@example.net")
    test_sign_in(wrong_user)
  end

  it "should require matching users for 'edit'" do
    get :edit, :id => @user
    response.should redirect_to(root_path)
  end

  it "should require matching users for 'update'" do
    put :update, :id => @user, :user => {}
    response.should redirect_to(root_path)
  end
    end
  end

  describe "GET 'edit'" do

before(:each) do
  @user = Factory(:user)
  test_sign_in(@user)
end

it "should be successful" do
  get :edit, :if => @user
  response.should be_success
end

it "should have a link to change the Gravatar" do
  get :edit, :id => @user
  gravatar_url = "http://gravatar.com/emails"
  response.should have_selector("a", :href => gravatar_url, :content => "change")
    end
  end
end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Show us user factory code. I guess that you using non-unique email for each user. Try creating email for user with the help of Factory sequence. Also, check you _test db on duplicate records.

Comment: For your user factory email you should do something like "user.sequence(:email) {|n| "email#{n}@example.com" }".  I think that's correct syntax, correct me if I'm wrong